# Prove that the number $6n+2$ is not a square for any integer $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

Prove, if $n \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $\left( 6n+2\right)  \neq b ^{2}$.

Just give me a hint. I've been trying to solve it for over na hour.

Comment: What remainders can a square leave upon division by $3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
0^2\equiv 0\\
1^2\equiv 1\\
2^2\equiv 4\\
3^2\equiv 3\\
4^2\equiv 4\\
5^2\equiv 1\\
$$
modulo $6$. So $2$ is not a quadratic residue mod $6$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What remainders $\mod 6$ can have squares of integers?